# gstreamer RTSP input cannot display

Tags: gstreamer

I am using an IP camera that sends rtsp stream with h264 codec.
On the client side, I can display the incoming stream via VLC using "rtsp://192.168.1.160/live/track0"

But when i am using the following gstreamer pipeline, nothing happens(no errors, no display, nothing)

gst-launch-1.0 rtpsrc location = rtsp://192.168.1.160/live/track0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
Furthermore, gst-discoverer cant find any streams from 192.168.1.160
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you want "rtspsrc" instead of "rtpsrc" in your pipeline. Also, I don't think gst-discoverer can give you any info about bare IP addresses. Do you get anything more interesting when using that command on the full RTSP URL?

Comment: have you tried setting the `GST_DEBUG` environment variable to some value to get more logs? (For example `GST_DEBUG=3`)

Comment: I have tried with both rtpsrc and rtspsrc, still no result.